# Splunk HTTP Event Collector Log4j2 SpringBoot unable to send data

Tags: java, spring-boot, splunk

I tried integrating my SpringBoot Application with Splunk, but could not get the logs. There is no Error in Console. Kindly help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{10}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>
        <SplunkHttp
                name="student-service-token"
                url="https://prd-p-wyalk.splunkcloud.com:8080"
                token="*********************************"
                host="localhost"
                index="student_idex_api"
                type="raw"
                source="http-event-logs"
                sourcetype="log4j"
                messageFormat="text"
                disableCertificateValidation="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m" />
        </SplunkHttp>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="splunkhttp" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Have you followed the [directions to setup](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.3/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector#Configure_HTTP_Event_Collector_on_Splunk_Cloud_Platform) the HEC token for Splunk Cloud? Can you submit data to that HEC URL via any other form (eg `curl`) with that token?

Comment: Yes, I tried following that, but from local i am not sure with URI Format.

Comment: http://http-inputs-prd-p-wyalk.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector/raw
Tried this but no luck